# Remove a section of a string in xsl

Tags: 2010, xslt, string

So I am doing a project in Sharepoint 2010 environment. I have an xsl template to retrieve the value of a page url. Currently this is the value that is being returned.

http://sitebuilder2/corporate/issues/Pages/issues/Pages/Operations/Hazardous%20Material%20Spill-Release/index.aspx

The value I need for the URL is:

http://sitebuilder2/corporate/issues/Pages/Operations/Hazardous%20Material%20Spill-Release/index.aspx

Is there a way within my xsl to remove the first '/issues/Pages' from my string so that the url returns correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assigned value of the URL to $myUrl variable just for the explanation

```
<xsl:variable name="myUrl">
    <xsl:value-of select="'http://sitebuilder2/corporate/issues/Pages/issues/Pages/Operations/Hazardous%20Material%20Spill-Release/index.aspx'"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

In your xslt you should be able to remove the first '/issues/Pages' as below

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($myUrl,'/issues/Pages'),substring-after($myUrl,'issues/Pages'))"/>
```

Result is

```
http://sitebuilder2/corporate/issues/Pages/Operations/Hazardous%20Material%20Spill-Release/index.aspx
```